# How do I add duration to string of format hhmm and convert it back to string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, int, varchar

I have two columns in a table that need to be added together.  One of them is a varchar(4) with military time, minus the colon, including preceding 0s.  Another one is an int which describes the duration of an appointment in minutes.  Basically I need to add the two together and keep it as a varchar(4), all in the same format as the first column.  I've used SQL before, but not in any sophisticated manner.  What would be the right approach to this?  Thanks!

I don't have to worry about stuff carrying over into the next day.

For example:

```
time:       '1145'
duration:   45
sum:        '1230'

time:       '0915'
duration:   30
sum:        '0945' (not '945')
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and then your expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assumption is that the question states the time will always be in 4 digit format hhmm. The query extracts hh and mm from the string and converts into time. The duration in minutes is added to this time value and then converted back to string format hh:mm using the [**CONVERT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function and the colons are removed from the string to get back to the original format.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd993/1)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE timevalues
(
        timestring  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   duration    INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO timevalues (timestring, duration) VALUES
    ('1145', 30),
    ('2345', 25),
    ('0815', 125);

SELECT      timestring
        ,   duration
        ,   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEVALUE, 108), ':', '') AS newtimevalue
FROM
(
    SELECT  timestring
        ,   duration
        ,   DATEADD(MINUTE, 
                    duration, 
                    CAST(
                            (   SUBSTRING(timestring, 1, 2) + ':' + 
                                SUBSTRING(timestring, 3, 2)
                            ) AS DATETIME
                        )
                    ) AS DATEVALUE 
    FROM    timevalues
) T1;
```

*Output*:

```
timestring duration newtimevalue
---------- -------- -------------
  1145        30      1215
  2345        25      0010
  0815       125      1020
```

Answer (score 2):

Its really ugly but gives you the result you want:

```
create table #temp
(
    militarytime varchar(4),
    duration int
)

insert into #temp values('1410', 10)
insert into #temp values('0415', 5)
insert into #temp values('1145', 45)
insert into #temp values('0915', 30)

select left(replace(convert(varchar, dateadd(mi, duration, convert(datetime, convert(datetime, replace(militarytime, right(militarytime,2), ':' + right(militarytime,2))))), 114), ':', ''), 4)
from #temp


drop table #temp

Results:
1420
0420
1230
0945
```

CAVEAT - there are most likely better ways - just showing another option.

Comment: None of the examples are particularly pretty :) Nothing against them, just that storing formatted strings often requires some lengthy code (unfortunately).

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you'd need to do this in exactly this way.

*Personally, I'd keep the data-types to be what yields natural behaviour in SQL-Server.  I'd deal with the formatting in the client, or anywhere outside of the database layer.  Keep presentation considerations away from data considerations ;)*

That said, I feel I've done my duty to make the universe a better place, and so I can now re-pollute it with what you actually want from us!

```
REPLACE(
  CONVERT(
    VARCHAR(5),
    DATEADD(
      MINUTE,
      [duration],
      CAST(LEFT([time], 2) + ':' + RIGHT([time], 2) AS DATETIME)
    ),
    8
  ),
  ':',
  ''
)
```

Comment: Basically I'm having to use it in the context of an argument of a function call in an SQL query to avoid problems of a different nature.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select left(New_Time,2)+RIGHT(New_Time,2)
from (
Select 
LEFT(
cast(CONVERT ( time , 
dateadd(minute, duration, --Dateadd will add the minutes to the time given.
Cast(LEFT(mil_time,2)+':'+Right(mil_time,2) as time) --This transforms the varchar into a Time format SQL recognizes.
),
8) as varchar),5)
 as New_Time
from (
select '2145' as mil_time, 200 as duration --This is the original data.
) Orig_tbl
) Time_Format
```

Comment: Not as pretty as some of the below answers, but very functional.

Comment: Just a note : Assumes SQL Server 2008+ *(Due to the TIME datatype)*